# app.yaml: max_concurrent_requests available in python flex environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

The [doc of the standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref) mentions that `max_concurrent_requests` can be set. But this setting is not documented in the [doc of the flex environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml)? I just deployed an app in the flex env with this option in the app.yaml and did not get an error. So can I assume it is also supported in the flex env?

And when doing websockets, with max_concurrent_requests=10, will having more than 10 simultaneous websocket connections result in an extra instance?

Comment: FWIW at least some of the configurations not applicable to /unsupported by some runtimes are just silently tolerated (i.e. won't cause an error), but they're not actually effective. I'd stick to just the documented ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is unfortunately no, `max_concurrent_requests` in App Engine Flexible is not supported. In order for it to properly function, it has to be used along with [`target_throughput_utilization`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#max_concurrent_requests), however, you will get an error as soon as you specify it in the `app.yaml` of the application.

The way of controlling as to "when" the application will scale in App Engine Flexible is by specifying a target CPU utilization with [`cpu_utilization`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#automatic_scaling) and `target_utilization`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

However my app is serving websockets (using asyncio) and primarily IO-bound. So network delay will occur before high cpu utilization. 

So what is advised way to make the sure the app scales up whenever delay on the websockets appears?

Comment: @toonknapen If your application is I/O bound, then the GAE Flexible environment wouldn't be the most appropriate. It would make more sense to use GAE Standard instead, and controlling scaling with `max_concurrent_requests` and `target_throughput_utilization`.

Comment: But I need websockets and these are not available in the standard environment. So what would you advice?

Comment: @toonknapen I did some digging regarding this, and it looks like you're correct - websockets are not supported in GAE Standard. In such case, the only other approach I can see is setting up your application on a [GKE cluster with Cloud Run for Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup). Cloud Run also allows setting up a maximum number of concurrent requests, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/concurrency) for reference.

Comment: thanks for the idea. I just started looking at 'cloud run'. However I discovered [inbound websockets are not supported there either](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues) :-(

Comment: @toonknapen In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#grpc_websocket) you have linked the statement of them not being supported is under the Cloud Run when fully managed section. However, [they are supported in Cloud Run for Anthos](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq#are-websockets-supported-on-cloud-run), which is different, because of its GCE-based native networking layer as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Google introduced target_concurrent_requests to App Engine Flexiable
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#automatic_scaling